# windows 10 any automated solutions from microsoft to remove clutter and leave a base OS

Tags: windows, windows-10

I just posted a question related to windows performance. Whilst doing the latest patches today 15th March 2017. Obviously the time it took to update install was impractical in the sense of interference with actual work. Regardless after updates I had 100% disk usage and I spent an age trying to locate processes that causes the underlying issue.

I found onedrive hanging around [so removed it](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_files/how-to-uninstall-onedrive-completely-in-windows-10/e735a3b8-09f1-40e2-89c3-b93cf7fe6994?page=2).  The indexing service was actually hammering machine too. I remove this. But found after first couple of restarts I had initially issues [getting into services](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-fix-app-has-been-blocked-your-protection-windows-10). Strangely enough it disappeared on it's own.

So question summary is considering there are so many processes yet left and in all honesty I really just a need basic windows OS rather than all the clutter. Does Microsoft provide an automated script to clean up the OS and provide a very basic OS. I think having to run around do regedits etc is not really fair on end user.

Comment: You can [reset or refresh](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options). You can also try running [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download), that may help a bit.

Comment: reset a refresh will only re-nable all the hard work i did to disable all the automated process. CCleaner relates to cleaning up general pc which isn't what i was asking. My question relates to `unwanted / unrequired / unused` windows system services most of which are windows stuff. To have a script official that comes from them rather than a third party that you can feel more trustworthy of that will just give you a basic windows 10 without all the extras

Comment: Can you give me some examples of the "automated processes" and "services" you disabled? What is unwanted/unrequired by you, like OneDrive and indexing, might not be for someone else...I'm not sure what tool you expect them to provide that knows what you want...

Comment: I have already mentioned a few above. The fact that there are no identifiable options during the upgrade no idea about install - to what should be running and what not is where the flaw and question relates to. Imagine a basic operating system that provides you with the essentials of network security i.e. firewall and whatever else it does there. It is rather a straight forward question there are fundamentally many processes running (meaningless) having to go away and look it up. Question is asking if MS provides a 1 page link that provides with a script (scripts) and a small desc of service

Comment: and what that service does. Ultimately there are lots of these processes running that as a developer I have no need for. In order to be able to run the bulky ide etc I would prefer a basic OS with none of the additional windows stuff that I don't use. is there any complication to what I am trying to ask/achieve ?.  If you are going to suggest but don't I use search. Answer is no I have installed cygwin and use bash instead using grep for those things.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but as I said, what may seem unnecessary to you is useful to someone else...But to answer your question, there is no MS-provided script to cleanup Windows. Sounds like you want something like the [LTSB](https://www.howtogeek.com/273824/windows-10-without-the-cruft-windows-10-ltsb-explained/) branch.

Comment: For the apps like one-drive etc, there are some powershell scripts that are googlable. The problem is that they are foisting some of the apps on you: if you do uninstall the apps, they will reinstall them on the next big update. I have had this happen twice now. Even the GetOffice app has been reinstalled.

Comment: who ever down voted please explain your reason. I keep my usage of windows to a minimal i.e. working hours. I don't really want to spend my evening / spare time researching the ins and outs of windows. I am suggesting the OS lacks a sensible approach for me as a developer to run minimal OS to preserve rest for my usage. I think any time people make a suggestion/dig at microsoft people treat it negatively. This is surely a positive point they should look at the concept and say yes maybe we could improve our product

Comment: I'd really like a solution for this